# How to save information in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to save information in a text file from a Tkinter-based app.

```
def SaveInfo():
    NameInfo = NameVar.get()
    SurnameInfo = SurnameVar.get()
    f = open('cv.txt', 'w')
    print (NameVar.get(), SurnameInfo)
    f.write(f'name - {NameInfo}')
    f.close()


NameVar = StringVar()
Label(MainInfo, text='Name ', padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=1, column=1)
Name = Entry(MainInfo, textvariable=NameVar).grid(row=1, columnspan=3,
        column=2)
SurnameVar = StringVar()
Label(MainInfo, text='Surname ', padx=5, pady=5).grid(row=2, column=1)
Surname = Entry(MainInfo, textvariable=SurnameVar).grid(row=2,
        columnspan=3, column=2)

Submit1 = Button(MainInfo, text='Submit',
                 command=SaveInfo()).grid(row=10, column=3)
```

It neither prints anything nor saves any information when I enter something in the Entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `SaveInfo` immediately in

```
..., command = SaveInfo())...
```

As functions implicitly return `None` unless otherwise directed, that's the equivalent of setting `command=None`, which does nothing.

You'll just want to reference the handler function, e.g.

```
..., command = SaveInfo)...
```

so Tk will call it when the user clicks the button.

As an aside, you may want to use the `a` (append) mode for writing instead of `w` (overwrite):

```
def SaveInfo():
    name = NameVar.get()
    surname = SurnameVar.get()
    with open('cv.txt', 'a') as f:
      print(f'name: {name} {surname}', file=f)
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are *running* the function on `Button` creation. Remove the parenthesis:

```
Submit1 = Button(MainInfo, text = "Submit", command = SaveInfo).grid(row = 10, column = 3)
```

Hope that's helpful!